# Display a gif image in Custom listview android?

Tags: android, image, listview, gif

I want to display a gif image http://peacechild.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/loading.gif
in each element of custom listview.
How to do that?
I know that we have to make use of the movie class but how to use it?
An example would be helpfull.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [this Animated GIF  app](http://www.anddev.org/resources/file/549) sample

OR

Use a webview to load it

Answer (score 0):

Use `VideoView`.

Natively `ImageView` does not support animated image. You have two options to show animated gif file

1.Use `VideoView`
2.Use `ImageView` and Split the gif file into several parts and then apply animation to it

Comment: any tutorial for that ??