# gif with Listview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-animation, animated-gif

I am new to Android. I Have **Listview** in My Activity and it's working Fine. But *suddenly in mind one thought* is going on. Is there any way to **put gif animation in background of my Listview** and **display data to on gif Image**. Let's say that In Our Listview we Have **set background color** as follow.

```
android:background="@color/Mycolor
```

so it can change the **whole Listview color** But I want to

> display gif Animation Like small Image of Birds are flying in
>   Background

. If it is possible then give suggestion.

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777315/showing-gif-in-android?

Comment: Yes I think keep gif as backgroud. Then overlay your listview on it giving it a transparent color. It will work:)

Comment: @Viren  give me any Useful link so I can try it.

Comment: @Do you know how to load gif???

Comment: Yes I make some Project on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940411/display-a-gif-image-in-custom-listview-android

Answer (score 0):

use an `Imageview` in row background and play `gif` on it using [this component](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way you can set,first you need to divide gif animation in indvidual frame,then you need to create one xml for background and use `animation-list` and add all the frames of gif image and set that xml as background

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame1"
        android:duration="1000"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame2"
        android:duration="1000"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame3"
        android:duration="1000"/>



    ....

</animation-list>
```

Comment: If I Use more then 10 drawable it's hang sometime.

Comment: if possible make your frames in less than 10 and try

Comment: Then animation can't smooth it's look like skipped 2 or 3 frame and then again start.

Comment: you can set background either with image or xml..if you add image directly it wil not work,,and xml i gave idea..i suggest use video view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104030/discussion-between-harshad-and-aditya).